# how to ignore the file if a string is not present using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am searching for a string in .gz files and trying to print the last line with a specific string. It is giving me 'list Index is out of range' if the string is not present. Below is the code I was working on

```
with gzip.open(files, 'r') as r, open ('output.txt', 'w') as w:
    string = [line.strip() for line in r.readlines() if b'STRING' in line]
    print (string[-1])
```

With the above code, I can print the last line if the 'STRING' is in the file. If it is not present it is throwing an error. In the else case, I would like to print "NO STRING PRESENT" or something like that. Any help in understanding this will really be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: If `'STRING'` is not in the file then `len(string) = 0`. You need to check that before attempting to print.

Comment: Basic debugging tip: if you have a list index that is causing a problem, look at the list!

Comment: What are you trying to do if STRING is not present?

Answer (score 0):

Use `try-except`:

```
try:
    print (string[-1])
except:
    print ("NO STRING PRESENT")
```

or write your own conditional. Start thinking on the lines of the list `string` itself, what its length would be in either case and then what would you want to do for each case.